# iterating over object in an array throws Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays `caNCourbeData` and `caN_1CourbeData` , each one contains 12 objects, and they have the same object structure.

this is an example of an object :

[image]

So what I want to do is to create a new array (`caCourbe`) that will contains a list of object as following :

```
{
   y : '2016-01',
   chiffreAffaireN : 1256.92,
   chiffreAffaireN_1 : -141559.33
}
```

`chiffreAffaireN` from `caNCourbeData[i].chiffreAffaire` and `chiffreAffaireN_1`  from `caN_1CourbeData[i].chiffreAffaire`.

So I did as the following :

```
var caCourbe = new Array();

caNCourbeData.forEach(function(i, caNCourbeDataElement){
    caCourbeElement = new Object();
    caCourbeElement.y = '2016-'+(i+1).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping:false});
    caCourbeElement.chiffreAffaireN = caNCourbeDataElement.chiffreAffaire;
    caCourbeElement.chiffreAffaireN_1 = caN_1CourbeData[i].chiffreAffaire;
    caCourbe.push(caCourbeElement); 
});
```

but then I get this error :

[image]

in my code I logged `caN_1CourbeData` and I get the array in the console, but I dont know why I'm getting that is undefined :

[image]

How can I solve this ?

## Edit 1 :

I tried to use forEach with `caN_1CourbeData` instead of `caNCourbeData` since they have the same length as the following :

```
caN_1CourbeData.forEach(function(i, caN_1CourbeDataElement){
    caCourbeElement = new Object();
    caCourbeElement.y = '2016-'+(i+1).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping:false});
    caCourbeElement.chiffreAffaireN = caNCourbeData[i].chiffreAffaire;
    caCourbeElement.chiffreAffaireN_1 = caN_1CourbeDataElement.chiffreAffaire;
    caCourbe.push(caCourbeElement); 
});
```

but I always get the same error and this time in this line : `caCourbeElement.chiffreAffaireN = caNCourbeData[i].chiffreAffaire;`

## Edit 2:

```
var caNCourbeData = [{
    "mois": 1,
    "nbFactures": 2,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 1,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 1,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "chiffreAffaire": 1256.92,
    "id": 0
}, {
    "mois": 2,
    "nbFactures": 4,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 2,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 0,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "chiffreAffaire": 413.00,
    "id": 1
}, {
    "mois": 3,
    "nbFactures": 3,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 3,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 0,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "chiffreAffaire": 30.00,
    "id": 2
}, {
    "mois": 4,
    "nbFactures": 0,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 0,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "id": 3
}, {
    "mois": 5,
    "nbFactures": 0,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 0,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "id": 4
}, {
    "mois": 6,
    "nbFactures": 9,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 1,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 0,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "chiffreAffaire": 2253.31,
    "id": 5
}, {
    "mois": 7,
    "nbFactures": 0,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 0,
    "nbContrat": 2,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "id": 6
}, {
    "mois": 8,
    "nbFactures": 0,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 0,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "id": 7
}, {
    "mois": 9,
    "nbFactures": 0,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 0,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "id": 8
}, {
    "mois": 10,
    "nbFactures": 2,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 0,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "chiffreAffaire": 450.60,
    "id": 9
}, {
    "mois": 11,
    "nbFactures": 0,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 0,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "id": 10
}, {
    "mois": 12,
    "nbFactures": 0,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 0,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "id": 11
}];


var caN_1CourbeData = [{
    "mois": 1,
    "nbFactures": 36,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 3,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "chiffreAffaire": -141559.33,
    "id": 0
}, {
    "mois": 2,
    "nbFactures": 144,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 23,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "chiffreAffaire": 19662.80,
    "id": 0
}, {
    "mois": 3,
    "nbFactures": 39,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 0,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "chiffreAffaire": 10835.42,
    "id": 0
}, {
    "mois": 4,
    "nbFactures": 30,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 2,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "chiffreAffaire": 12166.74,
    "id": 0
}, {
    "mois": 5,
    "nbFactures": 73,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 1,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "chiffreAffaire": 19391.04,
    "id": 0
}, {
    "mois": 6,
    "nbFactures": 36,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 5,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "chiffreAffaire": 23929.57,
    "id": 0
}, {
    "mois": 7,
    "nbFactures": 24,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 1,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "chiffreAffaire": 5446.59,
    "id": 0
}, {
    "mois": 8,
    "nbFactures": 24,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 0,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "chiffreAffaire": 3019.31,
    "id": 0
}, {
    "mois": 9,
    "nbFactures": 20,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 0,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "chiffreAffaire": 3178.76,
    "id": 0
}, {
    "mois": 10,
    "nbFactures": 1,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 0,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "chiffreAffaire": 10.00,
    "id": 0
}, {
    "mois": 11,
    "nbFactures": 14,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 2,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "chiffreAffaire": 6020.56,
    "id": 0
}, {
    "mois": 12,
    "nbFactures": 21,
    "nbFacturesReglees": 0,
    "nbdossiersRealise": 6,
    "nbContrat": 0,
    "nbContratConverti": 0,
    "chiffreAffaire": 4709.05,
    "id": 0
}];
```

Comment: please add the arrays as text as well.

Comment: Clearly `caN_1CourbeData[i]` is undefined, so the two arrays aren't the same

Comment: @NinaScholz please check Edit 2

Comment: @adeneo  please check Edit 2

Comment: A simple `console.log(i)` would have told you what's wrong.

Comment: i suggest to use `use strict` and declare all variables in advance, so in the callback `var caCourbeElement = new Object();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

switch the order of the arguments passed to your forEach callback, index is the second parameter, this works in my console:

```
caN_1CourbeData.forEach(function(caN_1CourbeDataElement, i){
    caCourbeElement = new Object();
    caCourbeElement.y = '2016-'+(i+1).toLocaleString(undefined, {minimumIntegerDigits: 2, useGrouping:false});
    caCourbeElement.chiffreAffaireN = caNCourbeData[i].chiffreAffaire;
    caCourbeElement.chiffreAffaireN_1 = caN_1CourbeDataElement.chiffreAffaire;
    caCourbe.push(caCourbeElement); 
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Parameters